# PostMessage error when transferring port in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a web app where I communicate with an iframe with some code I also control. I use Channel Messaging to communicate between the parent app and the iframe. It works without problems in Chrome and Safari, and also in Firefox, but in Firefox I get an error message.

In the iframe I initialise the channel:

```
// Setup channel messaging to the host
const channel = new MessageChannel();
channel.port1.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
    onRequest(event);
};
port1.start();
window.parent.postMessage('init', hostname, [channel.port2]);
```

On the parent side I listen for the 'init' message:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    event.ports[0].onmessage = ((event: MessageEvent) => {
        responseHandler(event);
    });
});
```

In Firefox only (tested om MacOS) I get the following error message: "ERROR TypeError: "event.ports[0] is undefined", and when looking at event:

```
ports: []
```

In Chrome and Safari ports like right and I don't get the error.

As said it works without problems anyway in Firefox, but how can I get rid of the error message?

Comment: Every other tab in your browser can also send messages around. You should really check wether `event.origin` is yours.

Comment: Yes, I do that, I just omitted it, because it wasn't relevant for my question.

Comment: Please set up a [MCVE], as it's currently written, it's a no repro for me on FF68 on macOS: https://jsfiddle.net/4b976jy0/

Comment: I just checked. I don't get this error anymore, I don't know what have changed.